# Python : Idiomatic way to get list with the lesser size

Tags: python, list, idioms

I have a list that holds other lists and I want to retrieve the list with the least elements. 
One obvious solution is :

```
list_of_list = ...
least = list_of_lists[0]
for list in list_of_lists[1:]
  if len(list) < len(least):
    least = list
return least
```

Is there a more idiomatic way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Use [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min) with [`len()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len) as the key:

```
min(list_of_lists, key=len)
```

This returns the shortest of the lists:

```
>>> import random
>>> list_of_lists = [[None] * random.randint(3, 10) for _ in range(10)]
>>> min(list_of_lists, key=len)
[None, None, None]
```

Comment: I was actually trying to find if I could change the behaviour of min() but I wasn't succesful. Thanks for the fast answer!